# Prevent pasting rich text in react-native TextInput

Tags: react-native, textinput, richtext

I'm currently experiencing an issue with a react-native `TextInput` where copying from the web into the `TextInput` preserves the formatting. Preserving formatting is unwanted.

For example, I copy text from [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut,_copy,_and_paste) and paste into my `TextInput`. This is the result:
[image]

How can I get the TextInput to ignore all formatting and just get me the plaintext? I've tried setting styles to force certain font sizes, weights, etc, but it does not appear to have any effect.

Minimal code example:

```
<TextInput
  multiline
  onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text: text.toString()})}
/>
```

Comment: Can you create a snack of it?

Comment: Try out https://github.com/apostrophecms/sanitize-html#readme

Comment: You might use regex